# How to add/remove event on screen resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Following is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handler = ev => {
      console.log(ev.data, src, ev.data.form);

      if (ev.data.type === "height") {
        if (ev.data.form === src) {
          setHeight((parseInt(ev.data.message, 10) + 10) + "px");
        }
      }
      if (ev.data.type === "popup") {
        if (ev.data.form === src) {
          setPopUpModel(ev.data.message);
        }
      }
    };

    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("message", handler);

      return () => window.removeEventListener("message", handler);
    }
  },
```

In web form I have a Submit button and it looks very good when I resize my screen the submit button gets cut like below:
[image]

Can anyone help me with what should I add to my syntax to solve this issue?

Comment: make sure its container allows it to be responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Attach the same listener for `resize` also

> If its possible please try to do this stuff using css itself, it will save you a lot of maintenance time!

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handler = ev => {
      console.log(ev.data, src, ev.data.form);

      if (ev.data.type === "height") {
        if (ev.data.form === src) {
          setHeight((parseInt(ev.data.message, 10) + 10) + "px");
        }
      }
      if (ev.data.type === "popup") {
        if (ev.data.form === src) {
          setPopUpModel(ev.data.message);
        }
      }
    };

    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("message", handler);
      window.addEventListener("resize", handler);

      return () => {
          window.removeEventListener("message", handler);
          window.removeEventListener("resize", handler);
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: I have tried it and it does not do anything same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
const [ height, setHeight ] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
 const handler = ev => {
   // here will be your existing code
 };
 
 if( typeof window !== "undefined") {
   window.addEventListener('message', handler);
   return () => window.removeEventListener('message', handler);
 }
}, []);

const handleClick = () => {
  // Define your click handler logic here
}

return(
  <div style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
    <button>
      style={{ height: height, minWidth: '150px' }}
      onClick={handleClick}
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: You have several syntax errors/typos in your code: "underfined" (should be "undefined"), you don't close the quote for the `100vh` style, your button element is closed before its properties are defined.

Comment: modifying the syntax errors now